# postgresql function return set of record

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have a situation where I want to use the returned values from one function to feed into another query.  My results are only one row and it should be about 700 rows.
Any help would be great.
here you can see that get_tbl_nm returns the requested values
I would like to feed these values into another select that will 
return all the colunm names

```
schedule_test=# select * from get_tbl_nm('schedule_test', 'public');
                    get_tbl_nm
---------------------------------------------------
 active_mode_configuration
 agile_lo_gain_adj_meas
 array_control
 assembly
```

-

```
 schedule_test=# select count(*) from get_tbl_nm('schedule_test', 'public');
 count
-------
   158
```

-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_col_nm(_db_nm text, _schm text)
 RETURNS text AS
 $stat_info$

 DECLARE
 tb_nm text;
 col_nm text;
 table_info text;
 db_nm text;
 schm text;

BEGIN
db_nm=_db_nm;
schm=_schm;

 FOR tb_nm IN SELECT * from get_tbl_nm(_db_nm, _schm)
 LOOP
  -- RETURN QUERY EXECUTE;
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format( SELECT column_name
         FROM information_schema.columns
         WHERE table_schema = _schm
         AND table_name = tb_nm)
      LOOP
     END;

   END LOOP;

   --RETURN table_info;
   RETURN;
END $stat_info$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What would you like the function `get_col_nm` to return? One or several columns? What do you intend by specifying all those variables that you neer use in your code?

Comment: declare tb_nm as `record` instead of text

Comment: What I was looking for is to have get_col_nm
return the value from get_tbl_nm and append the column name

 active_mode_configuration  id
 active_mode_configuration  name
 active_mode_configuration  home

Comment: What I have found is that I can get all the info I want for the table information_schema.columns
What I'm looking to be able to do is to use the information from the table information_schema.columns to gather statics 
I have modified the function
BEGIN   
FOR tbl_col_nm IN SELECT table_catalog AS DB1,
   table_schema  AS Schema1, 
   table_name AS Table1,
   column_name AS Column1
 FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = _schm
  AND table_name LIKE 'rec%'
     LOOP
        RETURN NEXT tbl_col_nm1 ;               
  END LOOP;
but this does not work

Comment: now I run 
select
sum(pg_column_size(id)) as total_size,
avg(pg_column_size(id)) as average_size,
max(pg_column_size(id)) as Max_size,
min(pg_column_size(id)) as Min_size,
sum(pg_column_size(id)) * 100.0 / pg_relation_size('tbl1') as percentage
from tbl1;

Comment: To create an output like this
Table | Size  | Coulmn   |total_size | average_size | max_size | min_size | percentage
------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------
tbl1  | 4 GB  |  id      |  5698     |   5698       |  5698    |   285    |     1.234     
tbl1  | 4 GB  |  col1    |  5345     |   1345       |  5698    |   632    |     4.453
tbl2  | 1 GB  |  Name    |  5765     |   8255       |  8255    |   123    |    56.400

Comment: I'm looking to automate this process

I'm looking to use the values from the one query for the column size and table size.